# GNOME: disable touchpad when external mouse is connected (keep dconf setting across sessions)

Tags: gnome, touchpad, dconf

I'm on Arch Linux + GNOME 3.32 + Wayland

I want the touchpad to be disabled when an external mouse is connected.
I know there's a [great extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/) for this that I've been using for long time, but it is currently (at time of writing) not working with GS 3.32 yet. So, I discovered that it can also be done via `dconf`:

To do so, I run dconf editor and set `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/send-events` to `disabled-on-external-mouse`

That works perfectly, however it is reset to `enabled` everytime I restart my GNOME session.
How do I make it persistent?

**EDIT:** I have found a workaround; see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as a workaround I added the following to `~/.bashrc` file:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/send-events "'disabled-on-external-mouse'"
```

This is executed at every login and restores the wanted settings